# How to link to the Yammer group in the message text?

Tags: yammer

Is it possible to link or mention group in the Yammer message?

For example you can mention people using @john and then select from the list the person. Does something similar exist for groups and if not what is the best way to link to the group?

Answer (score 7):

Use the following mark up: [group:#groupid#] where #groupid# is the ID of the group found in the URL.

Comment: Seems that this functionality used to work, but no longer does. Microsoft made an 'improvement' that broke it.

Answer (score 4):

No, the equivalent functionality is not available for groups. The best way to link to a group is to use the "web URL" for the group. This is a URL of the form:

```
https://www.yammer.com/{network permalink}/#/threads/inGroup?type=in_group&feedId={group id}
```

You can also link to a group using a URL of this form:

```
https://www.yammer.com/{network permalink}/groups/{group permalink}
```

Unfortunately, this URL can change over time if the group is ever renamed. The web URL, group ID, network permalink, and group permalink are all available via the API. Alternatively, the web URL can be obtained by copying the URL behind any group link.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:
[group:{group permalink}]
After posting, this string will be automatically changed to hyperlink to the group.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `[group:1234567]` has been broken by one the improvements Microsoft made.

Try instead using the usual hyperlink function

- select the text you want
- push the link button
- enter the url of the group you want to link to

It's ugly. You'd think that there'd be a better way, but it does work.